# Spinner not showing selected item, spinner loaded from an arraylist

Tags: android

I'm having a problem that I can't find a solution for.  I've looked and tried multiple different solutions as to why a spinner won't show the selected item.  It works fine when using a hardcoded array, but not with the ArrayList that I load in onCreate.  The spinner is populated but it won't show the selected item, the white space for the spinner just gets wider.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String[] test = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};
ArrayList<String> routes = new ArrayList<String>();
Spinner sp;
String[] routesArray;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
final static String routeURL = "http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/getroutes?key=";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, routes);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnRoute);
    loadRoutes();
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
//        routesArray = routes.toArray(new String[routes.size()]);
//        sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, routesArray));
//        routesArray = routes.toArray(new String[routes.size()]);
//        sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, routesArray));
//        sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test));
}


public void loadRoutes() {
    new RequestTask().execute(routeURL);
//        routesArray = routes.toArray(new String[routes.size()]);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String[], Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL routesURL = new URL(strings[0]);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(routesURL.openStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains("<rt>")) {
                    int firstPos = line.indexOf("<rt>");
                    String tempNum = line.substring(firstPos);
                    tempNum = tempNum.replace("<rt>", "");
                    int lastPos = tempNum.indexOf("</rt>");
                    routes.add(tempNum.substring(0, lastPos));
                }
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` is asynchronous which means it will run alongside other code. So, your code after executing the task will continue to run which means your `Adapter` won't yet be populated because `routes` doesn't yet contain any data.

**Solution**

Put the following code in the `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`

```
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp.setAdapter(adapter1);
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I <3 you so much. This has been driving me crazy for the past two days. I completely forgot that AsyncTask runs simultaneously and didn't even think about the adapter not being populated.